# Is the limit correct ? $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+e^{1/x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Is this correct ?

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{x}{1 + e^{1/x}} &= 0 \newline
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{x}{1 + e^{1/x}} &= 1
\end{align*}

Comment: The limit exists (and its $0$), which means that both the RHL=LHL, contradictory to what you've stated

Answer (score 2):

Since $0\leq\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}\leq 1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x =0$ we have:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}=0.$$

Comment: Thanks but I'm curious on the left hand and right hand limit

Comment: Both the left and right hand limit are $0$.

Comment: Thanks. I should have taken note of the numerator

Comment: You're welcome! Indeed $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}x=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}x=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x=0$

Comment: Also see the Squeeze theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Comment: Thank you so much